# How to freeze the Windows cursor in place?

Tags: windows, cursor, pinvoke

I want it to say **exactly** still and not move **at all**. Right now, I've found that the best way to come close to doing that, is to call the ClipCursor function (found in user32.dll) with a RECT that has a height and width of 1. The problem is that my cursor still moves, but only by a pixel or so. Even if I set the height and width of the rectangle to 0, my cursor still moves around by a pixel or so.

Not sure where to go from here.

Edit: I'm basically looking to replicate the functionality seen in MMORPGs and RPGs: when you rotate your character around by dragging your mouse, the cursor goes invisible and stays still.

Comment: Find an open source program that does what you want, and read its code

Comment: I have tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Use winapi [BlockInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms646290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
BOOL WINAPI BlockInput(
  _In_ BOOL fBlockIt
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be working in the game engine I'm using (Unity), and even if it did, I'm basically looking to replicate the functionality seen in MMORPGs and RPGs: when you rotate your character around by dragging your mouse, the cursor goes invisible and stays still.